# Maven test-compile works with openjdk-7; fails with openjdk-8 (cannot find symbol)

Tags: maven, java-8, java

**tl;dr** Upgrading java on my machine openjdk-7 --> openjdk-8 breaks my build

I have a working maven project configured to use Java 1.7.  Some notable dependencies are { `com.google.dagger`, `com.google.protobuf`, `com.nativelibs4java javacl` }.  I mention these because their generate-sources stages are non-trivial.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.10

```
$ uname -a
  Linux computer_name 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running Java 1.7 and Maven 3.0.5

```
$ mvn -version
  Apache Maven 3.0.5
  Maven home: /usr/share/maven
  Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
  OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

A snippet of my POM, demonstrating that I'm explicitly setting Java 1.7:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I confirm that at this point, `mvn clean compile` returns BUILD SUCCESS.

Now, let's upgrade the java install.  For the sake of not removing a long list of java-dependents, I'll first add java 8, then remove java 7.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
$ mvn -version
  Apache Maven 3.0.5
  Maven home: /usr/share/maven
  Java version: 1.8.0_40-internal, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
  OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

And now,

```
$ mvn clean install (heavily truncated)
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ physics ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to ~/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] ~/src/test/java/com/package/engine/EngineApplicationTest.java:[20,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EngineComponent
  location: class com.package.engine.EngineApplicationTest
...
[INFO] 18 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

The compile stage completes successfully.  The test-compile stage does not.  **All 18 errors are places where the test code tries to access code that exists in the main java code.**  It's as if the way maven puts together the classpath for the tests is somehow not parsing in the new, improved openjdk-8 compiler.

Additionally, I can confirm that there were no files in my local directory modified between runs of Maven.

And for the sake of completion, I'll update my POM (the actual goal of this operation)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Same result-- BUILD FAILURE.

Feel free to ask for broader code snippets.  I've done my best to avoid making this question even longer, but I realize I may have left out relevant information.

Comment: Same problem happened with Oracle Java 8.

Comment: I've happened upon some communal knowledge that new java compilers usually change the formatting of their errors, and the maven-compiler-plugin lags behind in its parsing abilities.  In other words, the error message I'm getting is incomplete.  I need to run javac manually to get the full picture.  Trouble is, I'm not sure how to, given the non-trivial code generation that happens in my build.

Comment: Never mind; in the time it took me to write my previous comment, eclipse found the generated files I told it to go get.  I can confirm that the tests build and run in eclipse, with java 8.

Comment: Well, as disappointing as it is, the workaround is [Project > Clean] in eclipse.  I can use maven for dependency management and eclipse to build.  This works in the short term because my project is nowhere near ready for public consumption.

Comment: Best is to run the whole build with `mvn -X clean install | tee mvn.log` and than [create a jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER) with that and furthermore it would be great if could share the code which is causing the problem....otherwise it's hard to fix this problem in Maven compiler plugin.